# MySQL replacing part of string with double quotes

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `T1` WHERE `c1` LIKE '%<span class="VBm">   </span>%'
```

results in 30 affected rows. I like to replace the four spaces with one space:

```
UPDATE `T1` SET `c1`= REPLACE(`c1`, '<span class="VBm">   </span>', '<span class="VBm"> </span>')
```

wont' work. Why? Is this a problem of double-quotes?

```
REPLACE(`c1`, '<span class=\"VBm\">   </span>', '<span class=\"VBm\"> </span>')
```

also won't work.

Comment: what is the result of your `REPLACE`?

Comment: using `UPDATE T1 SET c1= REPLACE(c1, '<span class="VBm">   </span>', '<span class="VBm"> </span>')` should work without problems... which result/error does the replace give?

Comment: i switched from V5.5.41-0 to 5.1.68 and the update works as expected.